Ctx response 404 even though the sign up function works normally(Next.js & Strapi)
I'm working on a project using Next.js and Strapi. I've set up a custom Strapi endpoint /api/auth/local/registers for user registration and using the server session, I wanted to re-send the email for users. When a user sign up, the registration process seems to work. The user is correctly registered in Strapi, an email sent, and successfully redirect to /confirmation/message. Otherwise, I keep receiving 404 Error from ctx.response
System Information


Next.js: v14.2.4
Strapi: v4.25.2
Node: v20.17.0
Npm: v10.8.2
OS: MacOS 14.6.1


Plus, I'm using the Caddy for https. I couldn't find any error with reverse proxy setting but here's code just in case.
Caddyfile
# Frontend server on localhost:3000
https://localhost:3000 {
  tls internal
  reverse_proxy localhost:3002
}

# Backend Strapi server on localhost:1337
https://localhost:1337 {
  tls internal
  reverse_proxy localhost:8000 {
    header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
    header_up Host {host}
    header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
    header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
  }
}

Here is the error message from the logs:
CTX: {
  request: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/auth/local/registers',
    header: {
      host: 'localhost',
      'user-agent': 'axios/1.7.2',
      'content-length': '64',
      accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-forwarded-for': '[::1]:60988',
      'x-forwarded-host': 'localhost:1337',
      'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
      'x-real-ip': '[::1]:60988'
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 404,
    message: 'Not Found',
    header: [Object: null prototype] {
      'content-security-policy': "connect-src 'self' https:;img-src 'self' data: blob: https://market-assets.strapi.io;media-src 'self' data: blob:;default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline'",
      'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-dns-prefetch-control': 'off',
      'x-download-options': 'noopen',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies': 'none',
      vary: 'Origin',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true'
    }
  },
  app: { subdomainOffset: 2, proxy: true, env: 'development' },
  originalUrl: '/api/auth/local/registers',
  req: '<original node req>',
  res: '<original node res>',
  socket: '<original node socket>'
}
CTX.SESSION: { email: 'test@gmail.com' }
CTX.SESSION.EMAIL: test@gmail.com
[2024-09-08 01:10:06.998] http: POST /api/auth/local/registers (3391 ms) 200

Next.js Code
signUpAction.ts:
export default async function signUpAction(...) {
  try {
    const strapiResponse = await axiosInstance.post(
      '/api/auth/local/registers',
      { username, email, password },
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    };
  
    if (strapiResponse.headers['set-cookie']) {
      return { error: false, message: 'Success!'};
    } else {
      throw new Error ('Session cookie not set');
    }
  catch (error) {
    return handleAxiosError(error as AxiosError);
  }
}

SignUpForm.tsx
export default function SignUpForm() {
...
  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmitting(true);
...
    try {
      const result = await signUpAction(formState, formData);
      setFormState(result);

      if (result.error && result.inputErrors) {
        setInputErrors(result.inputErrors);
      } else {
        // Ensure successfully set the session cookie before redirecting
        if (result.message === 'Success!') {
          router.push('confirmation/message');
        }
      }
    }
  ...

Strapi Code
email-services.js
const generateAndSend = async (user, subject, textContent, htmlContent, expiresIn = '1h') => {

  const token = generateToken({ id: user.id }, expiresIn);
  const textEmailContent = textContent.replace("{token}", token);
  const htmlEmailContent = htmlContent.replace("{token}", token);

  await sendEmail(user.email, subject, textEmailContent, htmlEmailContent);
};

// Function to register a new user
const registerUser = async (username, email, password, ctx) => {
  try {
    console.log('Request Headers:', ctx.request.headers);

    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      throw new Error('Missing username, email or password');
    }

    // Check if username and email already exists from checkDup
    await checkDuplicate(username, email);

    // Add the new user to the DB with confirmed set to false
    const user = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.add({
      username,
      email,
      password,
      provider: 'local',
      confirmed: false,
    });

    ctx.session.email = email;

    const verificationLink = `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/verify-email?token={token}`;

    const textContent = ``
    const htmlContent = ``

    await generateAndSend(user, 'Email Verification', textContent, htmlContent, '24h');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred in registerUser:', error);
    throw error;
  }
  console.log('CTX:', ctx);
  console.log('CTX.SESSION:', ctx.session);
  console.log('CTX.SESSION.EMAIL:', ctx.session ? ctx.session.email : 'undefined');
};


Steps:

Submit the signup form
POST request to the custom Strapi endpoint /api/auth/local/registers.
Strapi processes the request, creates the user, sends a verficiation email, set the server session.
404 response from ctx.response.

Github
For more context, you can check out the entire project on GitHub:
https://github.com/Tae-uni/snapjournal.git
What I've tried:
•   Verified that the custom endpoint /api/auth/local/registers is correctly hit by the frontend.  
•   Ensured withCredentials is set in axios to enable session cookies for the request.  
•   Verified that async/await is used properly to handle promises throughout the request and response handling.  
•   Confirmed through console.log that the code executes fully and reaches the endpoint without interruptions.  
•   Ensured that after receiving the set-cookie header, the user is redirected to the confirmation page.

Expecting:
•   I expected the POST request to complete without a 404 error.  
•   The session cookie should be correctly set, and the user should be redirected without issues.

